# JSON decode info from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm getting errors decoding JSON string.

ERROR:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

My php code:

```
<?php 

$socket = $_GET["socket"];

$bd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gestao_utilizadores" , "root" , "");

$getComponentes = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM componentes WHERE ( Socket=:socket )");
$getComponentes->bindValue(':socket' , $socket);
$getComponentes->execute();
$resultado = $getComponentes->fetchAll();

For ($i = 0; $i < $getComponentes->rowCount() ; $i++) { 
    $componentes = json_encode(array('tipo' => $resultado[$i]["Tipo"] , 'nome' => $resultado[$i]["Nome"] , 'socket' => $resultado[$i]["Socket"]));
    echo $componentes; 
}   

?>
```

My Javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'compatibilidades.php',
        data: { 
            socket: $("#board option:selected").attr('value') 
        },
        success: function(dadosRecebidos) {
            teste = JSON.parse(dadosRecebidos);
            alert(teste);
        }
    });
```

The error is on javascript or PHP?

Comment: You're echoing in a `for` loop, so you have several pieces of JSON, and together they form invalid JSON. echo only once instead, after the `for` loop

Comment: but i will get more than 1 info , what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$socket = $_GET["socket"];

$bd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gestao_utilizadores" , "root" , "");

$getComponentes = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM componentes WHERE ( Socket=:socket )");
$getComponentes->bindValue(':socket' , $socket);
$getComponentes->execute();
$resultado = $getComponentes->fetchAll();

$arr = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $getComponentes->rowCount() ; $i++) { 
    $componentes = array('tipo' => $resultado[$i]["Tipo"] , 'nome' => $resultado[$i]["Nome"] , 'socket' => $resultado[$i]["Socket"]);
    array_push($arr, $componentes);
}   

echo json_encode($arr); 

?>
```

Output the JSON only once, otherwise you end up with an output of several JSON strings, something like

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}{"key3": "value3"}
```

and that's not valid JSON

Comment: I get: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Then your PHP script is probably outputting HTML as well, and not just JSON, or an error occured.

Comment: What happens if you visit `compatibilidades.php` directly in the browser, what do you see ?

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\compatibilidades.php on line 19

Comment: That's an error,  now you need to check what's on line 19, and change it.

Comment: Just replace the last line with: echo json_encode($arr);

Comment: Thank you, now in javascript how can i get the param nome or tipo? can i alert(teste.nome) ?